Elasticsearch unable to sort by text field with keyword
Trying to sort the results
GET /books/_search
{
  "sort": [
      {"name": "asc"}
  ]
}

but getting the error:

Fielddata is disabled on [name] in [books]. Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.

Sure, so they suggest to use the keyword field. But, as far as I understand it I do have the keyword field:
> GET /books/_mapping/
   {
    "books": {
     "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         ...
         "name": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
             "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
             }
           }
         },

What am I doing wrong?

Even though you've got the keyword field defined as per the mapping you've shared, It seems Elasticsearch is trying to sort using the text field. When you perform the sort operation, you need to explicitly specify the keyword field like this:
GET /books/_search
{
  "sort": [
    { "name.keyword": "asc" }
  ]
}

